# Subtracting Columns in DataFrames based on results of another column

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a Pandas DataFrame like the following table:

CarFuel Volume Mazda 311.3 Mazda 310.4 F-15014.3 F-1509.7

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg" style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 122px">
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 56px">
<col style="width: 66px">
</colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Car</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Fuel Volume</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">F-150</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">25.01</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">F-150</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">22.47</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">F-150</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">19.56</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">F-250</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">9.87</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">F-250</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">6.32</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">F-250</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1.32</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to create another column based on the difference of fuel volume, but only if the fuel volume being subtracted is from the same model of car.  So the resulting DataFrame would look like the following:

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 0px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 0px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg" style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 144px">
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 52px">
<col style="width: 62px">
<col style="width: 30px">
</colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Car</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Fuel Volume</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Difference in Fuel</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">F-150</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">25.01</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">NaN</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">F-150</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">22.47</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2.54</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">F-150</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">19.56</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2.91</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">F-250</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">9.87</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">NaN</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">F-250</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">6.32</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">3.55</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">F-250</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1.32</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please make sure your Python code looks like Python code, not like HTML.

Comment: You can post the output of `print(df)`  or `print(df.head())` and format it as text. You don't need HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html), last add [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.abs.html):

```
df['Difference in Fuel'] = df.groupby('Car')['Fuel Volume'].diff().abs()
print (df)
     Car  Fuel Volume  Difference in Fuel
0  F-150        25.01                 NaN
1  F-150        22.47                2.54
2  F-150        19.56                2.91
3  F-250         9.87                 NaN
4  F-250         6.32                3.55
5  F-250         1.32                5.00
```